# Hard disk replacement for Asus Vivabook 14

Tags: motherboard, hard-disk, ssd

I have an ASUS Vivobook 14 laptop (model: X412D) which seems to have a *partial* disk failure: the computer boots to BIOS. The Windows OS on a live USB stick failed the repair process. I was able to retrieve the data with a live Ubuntu session from an USB stick, now I would like to change the hardware.

It seems like the computer was not equipped with a "standard" HDD or SSD disk (empty area on the bottom left without any connectors); hence I believe the equivalent hardware is part of the motherboard.

1. Where is it located on the MB? I have provided an image of the laptop interior.
2. Is it possible to change this piece without changing the whole MB?
3. Does it require soldering skills/equipment?

[image: ASUS Vivobook 14 laptop interior - motherboard and battery - grid as overlay]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine B4 and any connected squares, and you'll find there is a card-edge connector at the right end and a securing screw on the left end. This is an nvme PCIe solid state drive. I expect you can look up the specifications for your specific model computer and you may also find those specifications under the metal foil. The foil is a heat transfer medium and likely contacts a surface on the removed cover.

A small cross-tip screwdriver is all that is needed once the replacement is ready to be installed.

According to the [ASUS web site](https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-home/vivobook/vivobook-14-x412/) for that model, you have also a conventional spinning drive at B5, which may be the location from which you were able to retrieve your data and may not be defective/damaged.

Comment: I changed the defective NVMe PCIe SSD and the computer works well again!